# Is scratch card haram when it is given free instead of purchased?

Tags: halal-haram

In my scenario, a gas station is giving away scratch cards for filling fuel. If you fill for a certain amount, you get a scratch card for free with a chance to win something. You are not charged for the scratch card. In fact, the gas station themselves is losing money by doing this. They are doing this to attract customers to their station. The prices are car shampoo and cash. From my point of view this seems to be halal. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK... If the following two conditions are met it is permissible

---

### Condition 1

The price of the items purchased should be of their actual price i.e. the price should not be raised because of the prize. If the price is raised because of the prize then this is gambling and is not permissible.

### Condition 2

The customer should not buy the product in order to win the prize. If he buys it only because he wants to win the prize, and he has no need of the product, then this is a waste of money.

---

For more on this see :

- [Ruling on the incentives given by stores to attract shoppers](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/22862)
- [Are Free Lottery Tickets Halal?](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/7862/are-free-lottery-tickets-halal/)
- [Prize Draws if the Tickets are Free](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/8352/prize-draws-if-the-tickets-are-free/)